# Установить .deb файл node js

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, debian, node-modules

Как я могу установить файл формата .deb на компьютер пользователя используя node js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно сказать системе, чтобы она установила этот файл. `dpkg -i file.deb`. Для выполнения shell команд в node.js есть специальный модуль, узнать больше об этом вы можете здесь: https://dev-gang.ru/article/vypolnenie-shell-komand-s-nodejs-nl9nsyesrg/

Comment: Можно как-то вызвать окно ввода пароля? Так как для установки нужны права суперпользователя, а для них нужно ввести пароль, но пользователь в моей программе не имеет доступа к консоли.

Comment: @Maxim знаю, что это можно провернуть в python. Скорее всего в js тоже есть такая возможность (но это не точно)

Comment: Спасибо, в итоге нашел библиотеку sudo-prompt.